# Is it possible to make a subclass's constructor signature different to its parent's constructor signature?

Tags: c++

There is a base class :

```
class A {
public :
A(string a);
void some_method();
};
```

Implementation of A :

```
A::A(string a) {
cout<<"here it is : "<<a;
}
void A::some_method() { ... }
```

There is a class inheriting from A :

```
class B : A {
public :
B(bool b);
void another_method();
};
```

Implementation of B :

```
B::B(string b):A(/*what to write here*/)
{
cout<<"here it is : "<<b;
}
void B::another_method() { ... }
```

Is it possible to create this situation ? Is it possible for B to have a boolean parameter in its constructor whereas its parent's constructor param has a string param ?

Comment: `B::B(string b) : A("Hello, World! What else?") {}`

Comment: There is nothing anywhere that says they need to be the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is completely fine. It is ***not*** compulsory to pass the arguments from child constructor to parent constructor and you can pass all, some, none arguments from child class and add more constructor arguments if needed.

```
B::B(bool b) : A("Parent")
{
  cout<<"here it is : "<<b;
}
```

Comment: but the parent's constructor param should be given a value ?

Comment: Yes it must be given a value, which logically should come as argument of constructor of child class. But language poses no such requirement and you can source this argument from static, global, constant etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. You must correctly call the parent constructor with its correct signature, but your child constructor can have its own completely different signature.

```
B::B(bool b):A(string())
{
    cout<<"here it is : "<<b;
}
```

The above causes A's constructor to be executed with an empty string as an argument, then B's constructor to be executed with the `bool b` as an argument.